Extract raster files from netCDF in python and save them individually
I have a netCDF file that contains differents raster maps for different land uses of the world.
I want to extract this raster maps and save them individually because I have to make different thing to different maps.
The thing is, I achive to extarct the maps but they are saved inverted like in a mirror with an horizontal axes and in (what I think) negative values.
Does anybody know how to solve this?[The map in white is what I should get (I did it using QGIS) but I have lots of maps so I can not go one by one. The map in black is what I get](https://i.sstatic.net/T8DWPIJj.png)
I am using python, this is what I have so far
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import os
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr

    # Rute to the nc file
archivo_netcdf = "GCAM_Demeter_LU_ssp1_rcp26_hadgem_2015.nc"

    # Folder to save the raster
carpeta_salida = "E:\Modelos\LANDUSE change\Rotacion mapas"

    # if it does not exist create folder
if not os.path.exists(carpeta_salida):
    os.makedirs(carpeta_salida)

    # open nc file
nc = Dataset(archivo_netcdf, 'r')

    # Obtain the variables
variables = nc.variables.keys()

    # Iterate the variables
for var_name in variables:
    if var_name != 'latitude' and var_name != 'longitude':  # Omitir las variables de latitud y longitud
        # read raster
        raster_data = nc.variables[var_name][:]

        # Save raster as GeoTiff
        output_file = os.path.join(carpeta_salida, f"{var_name}.tif")

        # Georeferentiation
        x_resolution = 1.0  
        y_resolution = -1.0  
        upper_left_x = -180.0  
        upper_left_y = 90.0  

        # Create GeoTiff
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
        raster_count = 1
        dataset = driver.Create(output_file, raster_data.shape[1], raster_data.shape[0], raster_count, gdal.GDT_Float32)

        # Stablish georeferentiation
        dataset.SetGeoTransform((upper_left_x, x_resolution, 0, upper_left_y, 0, y_resolution))

        # Write in the GeoTiff
        dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster_data)

        # Define coordenate system (CRS)
        srs = osr.SpatialReference()
        srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)  # EPSG 4326: WGS 84
        dataset.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

        # Close GeoTiff
        dataset = None

    # Close the nc file
nc.close()

